# How to compute this integral $\int_{-\frac c2}^{0} e^{-a \left(\frac{b x^3}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)} dx $?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I want to compute this integral:

$$ \int_{-\frac c2}^{0} e^{-a \left(\frac{b x^3}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)}
dx \qquad\textstyle{with}\qquad a,b>0 \qquad\textstyle{and}\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}$$

The range of $x$ is $-\frac c2\leq x\leq 0$ where $c$ is a real positive and finite.

I use this code, but it does not work.

```
 Integrate[Exp[(-a (-(x^2/4) + (x^3 b)/2))], {x,-c/2,0}, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0 && b > 0  && a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals}]
```

I would appreciate any hints or comments.

Comment: Not all integrals can be expressed as a closed-form expression.

Comment: This integral seems to be impossible to solve analytically. If you are OK with its numerical evaluation you can reduce the number of parameters down to two by rescaling, say, like this: `x->z/2b`. Then the integral transforms into `NIntegrate[Exp[a1*(z^2 - z^3)], {z, -c1, 0}]/2b` where `a1` and `c1` are expressed through the old ones. Then it is possible to look for numeric values.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Is your comment on my previous post the case here too? I mean, since the limit of the function as $x\to 0$ is equal to $1$; does this mean that the integral diverges?  Here, the upper limit is zero; on the other hand, the limit as $x\to\infty$ is equal to zero.

Comment: @math2021: No. Your previous post was about improper integral that had `∞` as an upper bound. Integral with both finite bounds can diverge only if there is a singularity in the range of integration.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thank you very much for your quick response; it helps me a lot to proceed with my work. So, this integral, for sure, converges? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the integral "converges." (The correct term is "integrable," that is, the function is integrable over $[-c/2,0]$ because it is continuous. "Converges" is normally applied only to improper integrals, that is, integrals in which the function or the interval is unbounded.)

Comment: @Goofy Thank you very much for the confirmation.

Comment: $$\int_{-\frac{c}{2}}^0 e^{\frac{a x^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2} a b x^3} \, dx=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-4 (m+n)} a^m (a b)^n c^{1+2 m+3
   n}}{(2+4 m+6 n) m! n!}$$ Maybe it can be expressed by: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series with two  variables.

Answer (score 5):

You likely cannot get a nice closed form solution in terms of elementary and transcendental functions, but you can get a form expressed as an infinite sum and `DifferenceRoot`.

First get the $n$th coefficient of the Taylor expansion around zero:

```
coeff = FullSimplify[
 SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-a ((b  x^3)/2 - x^2/4)], {x, 0, n}], n > 0]
```

> DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {3*a*b*\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] - a*\[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] + (6 + 2*\[FormalN])*\[FormalY][3 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == 1, 
>     \[FormalY][1] == 0, \[FormalY][2] == a/4}]][n]

Then we just integrate term by term. A given term will have this form:

```
integratedTerm = 
 FullSimplify[(x^(1 + n)/(1 + n)*coeff) /. x -> -c/2, n > 0]
```

And the integral is just the sum of these terms which we can test with some values of $a,b,c$ here and using only terms up to $n = 10$:

```
N[Sum[-integratedTerm, {n, 0, 10}] /. {a -> 1.5, b -> 2.5, c -> 0.5}] /. {a -> 1.5, b -> 2.5, c -> 0.5}]
```

> 0.253843

... and note that this agrees with the direct numerical integration:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-1.5 ((2.5 x^3)/2 - x^2/4)], {x, -0.5/2, 0}]
```

> 0.253843